# Yellow bugs on mulberry

Tags: trees, bugs, mulberry

I have noticed several of these yellow bugs on my mulberry. What are they? Are they dangerous? Should I do something?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be some kind of cool yellow spider. Spiders aren't known pests for plants. So, I wouldn't be worried.

Perhaps it's some kind of [yellow crab spider](https://www.dreamstime.com/yellow-crab-spider-thomisus-onustus-well-camouflaged-flower-i-garden-sapin-image112490052). They can [change color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomisus_callidus).